# Easily select a bone in a bone

Tags: rigging

It is difficult to select the one in the bone. When I view the tutorial, it's easy to select at once. But I can't do that. I tried to solve it by pressing it several times. But I want to know the easy way.

[image]

Comment: Try the Outliner.

Comment: It is hard. T.T thanks